# Tooltip element with absolute positioning being clipped by container with overflow: auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a tooltip in a modal.

Is there a way that I can avoid the tooltip from being clipped by a container with `overflow` on it?

I need the modal-dialog to handle content overflow so I cannot remove the `overflow: auto` from it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal-dialog {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.tooltip::after {
  display: none;
  content: 'Hello';
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  top: -100%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 60px;
}

.tooltip:hover::after {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <span class="tooltip">Tooltip</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can't you use `data-toggle="tooltip" title="your text"` ?

Answer (score 9):

The `overflow: auto` rule will clip any content that overflows the container, as you have indicated. You would get a similar result with `overflow: hidden`.

Because your tooltip pop-up (hover state) is absolutely positioned, and the [**nearest positioned ancestor**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) is the tooltip trigger itself (`position: relative`), and this trigger is within the container with `overflow: auto`, there's no way to show the pop-up outside the container.

What you can do is make the nearest positioned ancestor an element higher up in the DOM structure. Then the abspos pop-up will reference that element, as opposed to the element with the `overflow`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;    /* moved here from .tooltip  */
}

.modal-dialog {
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tooltip {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.tooltip::after {
  display: none;
  content: 'Hello';
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;            /* adjust as necessary */
  top: 15%;             /* adjust as necessary */
  height: 20px;
  width: 60px;
}

.tooltip:hover::after {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <span class="tooltip">Tooltip</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque cupiditate ducimus, ea numquam est magnam quia ex consequuntur! Ratione modi dicta totam vel dolore, consequuntur nulla, amet labore odio voluptate!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this solution kind of works but only for this case. tooltips is a resuable component and I wont be able to position it as needed in each and every case. Also this is not responsive, things start to break. What I have found out after a lot of research is that this is not possible because of the way overflow: auto works.

Comment: I have found that this solution does work well (the answer is from a live site  I have). To make it responsive, simply adjust the offset properties in media queries.

Comment: but what if we have multiple tooltips in that container. we will have to set different values to position each of them. what if tooltips have directions, then we need separate positioning for each direction for each tooltip. i agree that it works for this case but it isn't scalable.

Comment: You're right. It's not a great solution. It's an ugly hack. But you're saying in your first comment that it's simply "not possible". My point is: if it's really important, then it can be done (with pure CSS).

Comment: yep. if someone actually needs this, it is possible. I will definitely upvote your answer and thanks for your help!

Comment: While this works for "escaping" content outside of the `overflow` container, it definitely doesn't work as a tooltip. For example, if you move the `<span>` in your example anywhere else inside the content, it doesn't work at all as a tooltip. However, this is a good trick to now that you _can_ escape content outside of an overflow, but it definitely doesn't work as a tooltip implementation.