# Show content outside overflow: hidden and transform: translate

Tags: html, css

Can I somehow show content outside of a div having overflow hidden and **also having transform translate**?

I have a slider where I want to offset the current slide position with transform, but I also want to be able to hover a child element within and make that popout of my overflow hidden. This is working in my example, but when I add the transform translate property, the child element gets cut off.

In my example try deleting the `transform: translateX(0)` on my `.slider` class and see how it works without it.

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 50px;
}
.overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
.product {
  height: 100px;
}
.product:hover {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="overflow">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="product">Slide1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="product">Slide2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y5c9xrrr/)

Comment: Why do u need the translate?

Comment: @SandrinaPereira I am creating a slider so I want to translate the property with a new value to make it slide in the desired direction :)

Comment: To use a slide, use a current plugin to do that in a proper way. The best I know is http://flexslider.woothemes.com/. In the demo it shows only images, but you can put anything inside of each  `<li>`

Comment: @SandrinaPereira actually I need to create this slider with Angular and most sliders doesnt allow for overflow elements to popout due to the way they Arne structured :)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40093740/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a slider, you can "move" the content with `margin`, instead of `translate`. Try it, it seems to work:

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 50px;
}
.overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
.product {
  height: 100px;
}
.product:hover {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
}

.slider {
   /* transform: translateX(-10px);*/
   margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="overflow">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="product">Slide1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="product">Slide2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea. I guess that could work. Not hardware accelerated then. Cant have both worlds I guess. I will try this asap.

Comment: I accepted the answer as it is, it works but not to my full desire :) See above comment