# Scroll an absolute positioned element visible outside of it's parent container

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the solutions mentioned in the responses actually work so I dared to ask the question again.

A table scrolls inside a fixed-height container. An icon inside the table column has an absolute position and need to scroll with the table. The icon however needs to overlap outside the edge of the container.

I tried setting overflow-x: visible and overflow-y: auto to the container element but that does not seem to work.

here is a code pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWpdpR

Thanks in advance

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 15px 5px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody {}

tr {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #aaa;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px dashed #888;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="icon">1</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="icon">2</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="icon">3</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Explanation of problem, and possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40093740/3597276

Comment: Hi Michael, I saw that post but my problem is slightly different. In the above example the tooltip is static outside the container, in my case I need to be able to scroll the icons with the table.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But the problem is still the same. The overflow will clip the absolutely positioned object. Not sure CSS can do what you want.